# Use Chrome Devtools with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One thing that's great about creating web apps is the use of Chrome Devtools. I'm able to open it up and type JS in the console to test out browser features.

When creating a Chrome Extension, it seems really difficult to test because while you can inspect the popup, you can't inspect or modify most anything else. This means you can't really see into your plugin and how it's working.

Is it possible to develop a Chrome Plugin and use Chrome's Devtools with it?